# I'm getting an error with RabbitMQ for Node.js on my Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm following along the "hello world" tutorial for rabbitMQ with javascript but I'm running into an error that I don't understand

When I run my `send.js` file using node, I get this error:

Error Message

[image: error message]

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5672
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1284:16) {   errno: -61,   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',  
address: '::1',   port: 5672 }
```

I installed rabbitMQ as stated in the tutorial using `brew install rabbitmq`. I start the server using `brew services start rabbitmq`. I've installed the required package using `npm install amqplib`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as my classmate followed the exact same instructions and it worked for them. I know that the rabbitmq server is running on my mac because when I type "brew services list" it shows the started rabbitmq server.

Comment: ECONNREFUSED shows up when the required server isn't running or is listening to requests. Are you able to open the rabbitmq console on your browser?

Comment: Try it with `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost. Some times it resolves to local IPv6 Address (`::1`) instead to its IPv4. My guess is that rabbitmq has it network sockets just bind to the IPv4 looback address. Run `netstat -tln` and post the output. Perhaps the server isnt even running.

Answer (score 5):

Can't comment yet, but for future Googlers I want to note that [@Marc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497655/im-getting-an-error-with-rabbitmq-for-node-js-on-my-mac#comment133207401_75497655) solved my problem (I am using macOS)

Try to replace `amqp://localhost` with `amqp://127.0.0.1` in your code